# Issue with jquery-ui .draggable and jqQuery events on a Marionette App

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events, jquery-ui-draggable

I have made a small app that allows the user to create rectangles, and drag them around.
The implementational details are that the "green" workspace area you see is a `Marionette CollectionView`
and when you are drawing boxes, you're essentially instantiating new rectangle models and rendering views for them. HTML-wise, the rectangles are child nodes of #workspace.

Here's a [working demo](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34144577/example/x-index.html) (on dropbox since jsfiddle keeps failing me all the time)

From what I know,in order to avoid the creation of a new rectangle while I'm moving around an already existing one, I need to `stopPropagation` of the `mousedown/mousemove/mouseup` events (That's what I'm using in the first place to determine if the user is dragging, to acquire mouse pointer position, calculate rectangle properties, and append the rectangle view on mouseup)

The problem is that although I `stopPropagation` for `mousedown/mousemove/mouseup`, apparently the `mouseup` event doesn't fire and the rectangle keeps following the cursor even after the mouse button has been released.

Also dragging a rectangle around is not as smooth as I would expect, but a bit glitchy. I'm suspecting that there must be either something horrible that I've done (most likely), or a conflict between how I'm handling events and how jQuery and jQuery UI are. (I need to comply, but I don't know how).

Please enlighten me!

Answer (score 0):

In the end I've decided to write a short jQuery UI plugin that would take care of all the calculations and would allow me better control over event handling.
For more information about what I ended up doing [check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144754/creating-a-jquery-ui-plugin-iife-return-object/20190543#20190543)