# Creating a jQuery UI plugin: IIFE & return object

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, marionette, iife, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I'm trying to create a little jQueryUI plugin that allows the user to draw rectangles on a `div#canvas`. The plugin extends `ui.mouse` and takes care of appending a helper, to visualize the process of drawing the rectangle, but **it doesn't actually render it**.

Instead, it should return a `boxProperties` object, but I haven't been able to do that.
I'm fairly new to IIFEs and haven't fully grasped closures but I suspect that the solution lies somewhere there. I've tried some stuff but in lack of proper knowledge couldn't achieve anything.

The catch is that `div#canvas` *(where the rectangles are drawn)*, is actually a `Marionette.CollectionView` and the rectangles themselves are going to be `Marionette.ItemView` added dynamically to the collectionview, which will render them as soon as they're drawn.

What should I add to my code, so that as soon as a rectangle is drawn, a boxProperties object is returned so that I can pass it to the rectangle ItemView in order to get it rendered?

Here's my plugin code

```
(function($, undefined){
    $.widget('nc.boxMaker', $.ui.mouse, {
        version: '0.0.1',

        options: {
            distance: 60
        },

        _create: function() {
            el = this.element;
            screenOffset = el.offset();
            screenOffset.left = Math.round(screenOffset.left);
            screenOffset.top = Math.round(screenOffset.top);
            this._mouseInit();
        },

        _mouseStart: function(event) {
            this.coords = [event.pageX - screenOffset.left, event.pageY - screenOffset.top];
            this.boxHelper = $(document.createElement('div'));

            this.boxHelper.css({
                "border":'1px dotted black',
                "z-index": 100,
                "position": "absolute",
                "left": this.coords[0],
                "top": this.coords[1],
                "width": 10,
                "height": 10
            });
            el.append(this.boxHelper);
        },

        _mouseDrag: function(event) {
            var x1 = this.coords[0], y1 = this.coords[1], 
                x2 = event.pageX - screenOffset.left, y2 = event.pageY - screenOffset.top;
            if (x1 > x2) { var tmp = x2; x2 = x1; x1 = tmp; }
            if (y1 > y2) { var tmp1 = y2; y2 = y1; y1 = tmp1; }
            boxProperties = {left: x1, top: y1, width: x2-x1, height: y2-y1};
            this.boxHelper.css(boxProperties);
        },

        _mouseStop: function(event) {
            this.boxHelper.remove();
            return boxProperties;
        }

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used jQuery-UI [`_trigger` method](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/#method-_trigger)

```
    _mouseStop: function(event) {
        this.boxHelper.remove();
        console.log("about to trigger view event!")
        this._trigger("stoppedDrawing", event, boxProperties);
    }
```

So whenever the _mouseStop method is called, we're gonna remove the helper rectangle,
and trigger an event of type `"stoppedDrawing"` and also pass the `boxProperties`.
Note that the full event type will be `"boxmakerstoppeddrawing"` because I've named my jquery-ui plugin `boxMaker`.

Now back in my Marionette.CollectionView i initialize the view

```
  initialize: function() {
    this.$el.boxMaker(); 

  },
```

And then I add my events

```
  events: {
    'boxmakerstoppeddrawing' : 'drawingHandler'
  },
```

Since I'm calculating stuff  I have a function on my `itemViewOptions`, that returns the `boxProperties` object

```
  itemViewOptions: function() {
    return boxProperties;
  }
```

Last but not least I have my drawingHandler, that takes care of creating an instance of the Rectangle model, with the boxProperties, and adding it to the collection (which takes care of appending it)

```
  drawingHandler: function() {
    var rectangle = new Rectangle();
    this.collection.add(rectangle);
  }
```

Comment: did u release the plugin? i want to implement the same functionality eg. a user can create a rectangle on the canvas using mouse and then assign it the width and height through some variables. when the values of the variables are updated, the rectangle is redrawn.